# Bootstrap 4: Force input form to take up entire width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to force a search box to take up the entire width of the container, but I can only ever get it to take up roughly half the width.  Here is some representative code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="submitted_word" type="text" class="flex-fill mr-2 form-control" placeholder="Enter Words Here">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit Word</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And a link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ovLab58u/

I've followed every one of the answers listed here, and nothing seems to be working: [Bootstrap 4 inline form full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844588/bootstrap-4-inline-form-full-width)

Comment: Make `.input-group` a block element or add `width: 100%` to it

Comment: What do you mean by "a block element?"

Comment: The display property of the element currently is `table`. Set it to `block` to use the full length.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display: block` style to the `div` having class `input-group` either as inline style or as external css class

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group" style="display: block;">
                    <input id="submitted_word" type="text" class="flex-fill mr-2 form-control" placeholder="Enter Words Here">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit Word</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yep - that works. Don't know why you would include this particular version of Bootstrap - 4.0.0-alpha.2 - but changing from table to block does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> I just add bootstrap v4.4 CDNs from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/ to your code and also add a "div closed tag" that you did not closed in your code. and it works correctly. like the code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
   
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="submitted_word" type="text" class="flex-fill mr-2 form-control" placeholder="Enter Words Here">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit Word</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```